# AFJSONResponseSerializer not allow underscore in the response body

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

I am using Afnetworking 3.1.0 for iOS app. My JSON response has a '_' (underscore) sing as bellow.

```
response --> {"_body":{"data":{"
```

Android app can serialize same response without any issue, which is using okhhtp3.

I suspect, `AFJSONResponseSerializer` is the culprit. I have tried as bellow to set acceptableContentType to `AFJSONResponseSerializer`. But does not work.

```
self.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializerWithWritingOptions:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted];
    self.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    self.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/html", nil];
```

Anyone has idea how to resolve this, please share.

Comment: It uses `NSJSONSerialization` See there: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/7642bcf6596c7c088b08dfd256050390d462df9b/AFNetworking/AFURLResponseSerialization.m I guess the issue is with `NSJSONSerialization`, can you check it by doing a test with `NSJSONSerialization` and see if it parse it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue is not in AFNetworking. Problem is in the `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock` method which I am using to construct a customize JSON from the response.

`enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock`  is ignoring object inside an object.